# phpmyadminで既存テーブルのcreate文を表示したい

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadminでテーブルを作成したのですが、他の環境でも同じテーブルが作成できるようにsql文が欲しいのですが参照する方法はあるのでしょうか。
・テーブルのcreate文

尚、作成の際は表示されているボタンなどを使用してしまったため自身でSQLを打ち込んでいません。
一から作成するにはデータ量が多いので、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLでも実行できます。SQL実行タブで以下を実行してもらえればと思います。

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;
```

（参考）
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

コピーしたいテーブルを開き、エクスポートタブを選択
デフォルト（SQL）状態で、実行するボタンを押下するとCREATE文とINSERT文が表示される